# Is the YQL console unavailable for anyone else?

Tags: yql

Is anyone else having trouble getting into the YQL console site to edit any scripts - https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console

I have tried to open  from multiple browsers on multiple devices, but I can only get the message...

"Yahoo! Will be right back...Thank you for your patience. Our engineers are working quickly to resolve the issue."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question itself is not about programming and just asking if an off-site service is currently working.  (Which it is not, I see the same message.)

Comment: I'm getting the same message, I tested from different regions across the world and got the same message.

Comment: I this this topic should remain open, because Yahoo direct all uses to SO stack overflow and tell them to use the "YQL" tag.  I know this isn't  a SO type question. But I hope SO Mods will give it consideration because Yahoo does direct users here with issues.

Comment: What about Open Data Tables? All my tables hosted on their site are gone. Looks like this is the beginning of the end for YQL as a free easy-to-use public service.

Answer (score 1):

I am also having this issue, and the YQL forums directs users to SO. I have been having this issue since May 4th around 1800 GMT. I have begun to wonder if Yahoo is even aware of the problem since it has been nearly 5 days now. My queries were not even executing on Fri or Sat, but theyre now intermittently returning results yet the console is still offline.

You can use the *Sample YQL Response* page at https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/ to create new queries but editing saved queries is not possible at the moment.